# Minipage misalign horizontally 2 long side-by-side tables and cause them to overlap, even though plenty of space free

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable, minipage, sidebyside, overlap

I use `minipage` to place 2 tables side-by-side. I can make the tables readable, but isn't there a way to make them equally distanced from vertical margins and horizontally aligned to each other?

When I alter parameters, either are the tables being overlapped, or misaligned with onee another, or the right table continues off/across page, causing the rest of the right table not to be seen.

Do I need to change the font size? Have already unsuccesfully tested `\tiny` and `{5cm}`. Other commands didn't change the font/table size at all. It only moves right or left. Is the problem in `{0.4textwidth}`?

**edit1**: Can anyone say how **make minipage occupy more space in the a4 pagewidth?**.

**edit2**: It is requirement to use side-by-side tables (due to numerous lines I will be inserting). I have LOTS of long tables and there are not many pages left (so if those tables are side-by-side organized, it will spare me space).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,titlepage,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{boxedminipage}
    \usepackage{geometry} \usepackage{theorem}      \usepackage{fancybox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{ifthen}       \usepackage{url}       
    \usepackage{afterpage} \usepackage{color}       \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{makeidx}      \usepackage{indentfirst}  
    \usepackage{subfig}   \usepackage{booktabs}     \usepackage{scalefnt}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}  \usepackage[brazilian]{babel} \usepackage{epsfig}         
    \usepackage{epstopdf}   \usepackage{subfigure}  \usepackage{amsfonts} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}    \usepackage{amssymb}  
    \usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}
  \par This is a normal paragraph and my interest is to make the minipage vertical limits to be larger than this paragraph textwidth. Possibly will the tables side-by-side fit in perfectly 
  \begin{table}[!htb]
    \caption{Resultado da clusterização por perdas totais em MT, BT com o algoritmo Ward}
    \label{TabClusterização1a}
    %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule   \textbf{Nº} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Clusters agrupados}} 
    & \textbf{SR$^2$} 
    & \textbf{R$^2$}  \\ 
\midrule                
   54 & CEEE-D & EBO & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline 
   53 & EMS &COSERN & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
   52 & CPFL SANTA CRUZ & CNEE & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
   51 & DEMEI &EEB & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
   50 & EEVP &RGE SUL & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ 
\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{minipage} 
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
    27 & LIGHT& CL50 & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\ \cline{1-5} 
    26 & CL34 &ELEKTRO & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\ \cline{1-5}
    25 & CL46&COOPERALIANÇA & 0.0001 & .999 \\ \hline
    24 & EFLUL &CL38 & 0.0001 & .999 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
     \end{minipage}
      \end{table}
       \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. Without knowing the dimensions and margins of your page it is quite hard to tell you why your tables don't fit.

Comment: Your table are simply to wide that can be fit in `o.4\textwidth` even if they use `\tiny` font size. You need to put your table one after other.

Comment: It is not too wide because I have seen the same tables side-by-side in scientific paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, your tables are to wide (even if you use `\tiny` font size)  that they can be put in parallel in your document. A reasonable solution is merging them into one table as follows:

[image]

As you can see, I prefer tables with only necessary horizontal rules, for which I use rules from the `booktabs` package and for numbers the `S` column types:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,titlepage,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Resultado da clusterização por perdas totais em MT, BT com o algoritmo Ward}
\label{TabClusterização1a}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X X S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.3]}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{Núm.\\ Clust.}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Clusters agrupados}}
        &   {\thead{SR$^2$}}    &   {\thead{R$^2$}}     \\ 
    \midrule
54 & CEEE-D             & EBO           & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\  
53 & CPFL PAULISTA      & BANDEIRANTE   & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\  
52 & CPFL SANTA CRUZ    & CNEE          & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\  
51 & DEMEI              & EEB           & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\  
50 & EEVP               & RGE SUL       & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
    \addlinespace  
27 & LIGHT              & CPFL LESTE PAULISTA   
                                        & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\ 
26 & CL34               & ELEKTRO       & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\ 
25 & CPFL PIRATININGA   & COOPERALIANÇA & 0.0001 & .999 \\ 
24 & EFLUL              & CL38          & 0.0001 & .999 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Let mi demonstrated a way, how you can put your two tables in parallel. For this are used the following tricks:

- for font size is selected `\footnotesize`
- prescribed tables' width are `0.49\linewidth` and with this enabled multi lines text in cells
- used are only lowercase letters in cells' texts

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,titlepage,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{Resultado da clusterização por perdas totais em MT, BT com o algoritmo Ward}
\label{TabClusterização1a}
\begin{tabularx}{0.49\linewidth}[t]{@{}c LL S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.3]@{}}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{N. C.}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Clusters agrupados}}
        &   {\thead{SR$^2$}}    &   {\thead{R$^2$}}     \\
    \midrule
54 & ceee-d             & ebo           & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
53 & cpfl paulista      & bandeirante   & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
52 & cpfl santa cruz    & cnee          & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
51 & demei              & eeb           & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
50 & eevp               & rge sul       & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\,%
\begin{tabularx}{0.49\linewidth}[t]{@{}c LL S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.3]@{}}
    \toprule
\thead[b]{N. C.}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Clusters agrupados}}
        &   {\thead{SR$^2$}}    &   {\thead{R$^2$}}     \\
    \midrule
27 & light              & cpfl leste paulista
                                        & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\
26 & cl34               & elektro       & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\
25 & cpfl piratininga   & cooperaliança & 0.0001 & .999 \\
24 & eflul              & cl38          & 0.0001 & .999 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read my edit PS1 and PS2. You mean they are too wide to fit in page width or to fit in the text width (respecting vertical margins preset in documentclass)? I have seen the same table side-by-side in scientific paper. They were broader however than the text frame width, so they are not too wide to fit in a4 page.

Comment: @amandinhahot10,  you can put two tables side by side only if the sum of the tables' natural width are smaller than `\textwidth` what is not in your case. With other words, you can not put elephant in lady suitcase (even if you polite ask him :-) . With some small tweaks are possible to shrink your tables width using only lowercase letters and smaller fonts and allow two line text in the 2. and 3. column (see addendum to answer) but I doubt that this trick will spare some space in in your document. Regarding your tables, which you can't fit on page, see if `longtable` can help you.

Comment: @amandinhahot10, I do not understood you. Please read some introductory text about tables, for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables. And please, near in mind, this is Q & A site, not forum. If you have new question, please ask it. People around here will help you to solve to LateX related question.

Comment: @amandinhahot10, apparently you not have installed this package. Install it (by help of some tools contained in your LaTeX installation, for example "console" in MikTeX).

Comment: 1) `longtable` is an useful tip, however doesn't fit requirement (please see my updated edits). 2) Your addendum code compiled, but only left table is being displayed. I installed all the packages. Q&A means I can't add details? I asked about side-by-side tables and your first answer mentioned single table. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @amandinhahot10, ask new question. I will suggest to close your question as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `adjustbox` but I advise you not to put them side-by-side, think of your long-sighted readers.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,titlepage,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{boxedminipage}
    \usepackage{geometry} %\usepackage{theorem} you also add new theorem
    \usepackage{fancybox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{ifthen}       \usepackage{url}       
    \usepackage{afterpage} \usepackage{color}       \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{rotating} \usepackage{makeidx}      \usepackage{indentfirst}  
    %\usepackage{subfig} you also add subfigure
    \usepackage{adjustbox}% added
    \usepackage{graphicx}% added
    \usepackage{caption}% added
    \usepackage{multirow}% added
    \usepackage{booktabs}     \usepackage{scalefnt}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}  \usepackage[brazilian]{babel} \usepackage{epsfig}         
    \usepackage{epstopdf}   \usepackage{subfigure}  \usepackage{amsfonts} 
    \usepackage{amsmath}    \usepackage{amssymb}  \usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\begin{document}
Do you want something like Table \ref{TabClusteriz}?% I would not use special char in labels

Isn't Table \ref{mytab} much more readable?

 \begin{table}[tbp]\centering
 \caption{\label{TabClusteriz}Resultado da clusterização por perdas totais em MT, BT com o algoritmo Ward}  
  \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
     \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
       \textbf{Número} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Clusters agrupados}} 
        & \textbf{SR$^2$} 
        & \textbf{R$^2$}  \\ \cline{2-3} 
        \textbf{de Clusters} &&&&\\ \hline
        54 & CEEE-D & EBO & 0.0000 & 1.00                 \\ \hline 
        53 & CPFL PAULISTA & BANDEIRANTE & 0.0000 & 1.00  \\ \hline
        52 & CPFL SANTA CRUZ & CNEE & 0.0000 & 1.00       \\ \hline 
        51 & DEMEI &EEB & 0.0000 & 1.00                   \\ \hline 
        50 & EEVP &RGE SUL & 0.0000 & 1.00                 \\ \hline
       \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}[t]{c|c|c|c|c}
        27 & LIGHT& CPFL LESTE PAULISTA & 0.0001 & 1.00     \\ \cline{1-5} 
        26 & CL34 &ELEKTRO & 0.0001 & 1.00                  \\ \cline{1-5}
        25 & CPFL PIRATININGA & COOPERALIANÇA & 0.0001 & .999 \\ \hline
        24 & EFLUL &CL38 & 0.0001 & .999                     \\ \hline
       \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[tbp]\centering
 \caption{\label{mytab}Resultado da clusterização por perdas totais em MT, BT com o algoritmo Ward}     \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
       \textbf{Número} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Clusters agrupados}}} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{SR$^2$}} 
        & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{R$^2$}}  \\ 
        \textbf{de Clusters} \\ 
        \midrule
        54 & CEEE-D & EBO & 0.0000 & 1.00                 \\  
        53 & CPFL PAULISTA & BANDEIRANTE & 0.0000 & 1.00  \\ 
        52 & CPFL SANTA CRUZ & CNEE & 0.0000 & 1.00       \\  
        51 & DEMEI &EEB & 0.0000 & 1.00                   \\ 
        50 & EEVP &RGE SUL & 0.0000 & 1.00                 \\ 
        27 & LIGHT& CPFL LESTE PAULISTA & 0.0001 & 1.00     \\  
        26 & CL34 &ELEKTRO & 0.0001 & 1.00                  \\ 
        25 & CPFL PIRATININGA & COOPERALIANÇA & 0.0001 & .999 \\ 
        24 & EFLUL &CL38 & 0.0001 & .999                     \\ 
        \bottomrule
       \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed I want table 1 (please red edit1,2 and 3), but yours is still horizontally misaligned and as I add more lines to the table, code won't compile. To make the side-by-side tables more readable, how would you make the minipage occupy more space of the A4 page width?

Comment: @amandinhahot10 Zarko has already replied with what you want, so it is useless to update my answer.

Comment: CarLaTeX you can still say how to fix that horizontal alignment. I found your answer also very much helpful.

Comment: @amandinhahot10 See Andrew's answer

Answer (score 3):

You can make these fit using `\tiny`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,titlepage,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[thmmarks,amsmath]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{theorem}

\begin{document}
This is a normal paragraph and my interest is to make the minipage
vertical limits to be larger than this paragraph textwidth. Possibly
will the tables side-by-side fit in perfectly
\begin{table}
  \caption{Resultado da clusterização por perdas totais em MT, BT com
  o algoritmo Ward}
  \label{TabClusterização1a}
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \tiny \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
      \toprule   \textbf{Nº} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Clusters agrupados}}
      & \textbf{SR$^2$}
      & \textbf{R$^2$}  \\
      \midrule
      54 & CEEE-D & EBO & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
      53 & EMS &COSERN & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
      52 & CPFL SANTA CRUZ & CNEE & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
      51 & DEMEI &EEB & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\ \hline
      50 & EEVP &RGE SUL & 0.0000 & 1.00 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.46\linewidth}
    \tiny
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
      27 & LIGHT& CL50 & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\ \hline
      26 & CL34 &ELEKTRO & 0.0001 & 1.00 \\ \hline
      25 & CL46&COOPERALIANÇA & 0.0001 & .999 \\ \hline
      24 & EFLUL &CL38 & 0.0001 & .999 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that a `minipage` command does not resize any table, it just makes the containing box of the specified with, and material that is too wide just sticks out.  Examining the log file gives information about how much the material is overflowing, in Overfull box warnings.   The sum of the widths of your `minipages` should be less than `\linewidth`.  In the above code I have made them large enough so that there are no overfull box warnings.